# Use of instance member '' on type '''; did you mean to use a value of '' type instead?

Tags: swift, core-data

Error below is caused by the '`let managedObjectContext = getMainContext()`' line of code, whats causing this as I couldnt see why i wouldnt be able to use the function without issue

> Use of instance member 'getMainContext' on type 'RoutineController'; did you mean to use a value of type 'RoutineController' instead?

```
    fileprivate lazy var fetchedExercisesTodayController: NSFetchedResultsController<UserExercise> = {

    let managedObjectContext = getMainContext()
    let userExercise = UserExercise(context: managedObjectContext)

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserExercise> = UserExercise.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(usersroutine == %@)", self.routineName)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)] //this isnt really needed

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}()

func getMainContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if you add `self.` it will fix your problem.

```
let managedObjectContext = self.getMainContext()
```

When using a computed variable you need to specify self to access the correct method.

Hope this helps